# Am I able to run firebase emulators with "forever" module?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, forever, forever-monitor

I am running a nodejs server locally with Firebase emulators (using `firebase emulators:start`). I have another version running on google cloud functions - but I also need something running locally.

When errors happen, my whole node process dies, and the emulator dies etc... and I have to go back and restart the process manually. Is there a way to automatically restart it when an error happens, such as using `forever`? I tried with something like `forever start  firebase emulators:start` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how Firebase is built and operates, it does not support any such functionality of staying awake as a process virtually non-stop. You would most likely need to refactor your code in such a way that the process you need to keep alive indefinitely is separated from your code hosted by the firebase emulator.